# Not able to launch instance from the ami image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

There is an ec2-instance which I have to taken an AMI backup, After the backup is complete we are trying to launch the server using the AMI backup, The machine is getting launched but the status check is not getting stable it remains in the "Initializing State". What to do? How to resolve it?

Comment: How long did you wait? When i searched Google someone asked this question, the instance was doing a file system check. How large is the disk?

Comment: Please add information about the device configuration and numbering of the AMI. Also, the exacpt operating system and version/distribution might be of help.

Comment: Hello @Tim i have waited for more than 30mins but still it was not coming up

Comment: Hello @GLATKI.M the AMI image is a ubuntu 16.04 instance type that we are trying to launch is m5.large

Comment: Get the screenshot from the console as was suggested below, and add it to the question. Also, give it more time. If it's checking a large file system it can take a while since it's network attached disk.

Answer (score 0):

#### Few things to check

- Get an EC2 screenshot from AWS console so you can get more details what is OS doing.
- Try to change instance type to m4 since it does not use enhanced networking. Link below describes enhanced networking in detail and its prerequisites. I suspect you don't have correct driver or meet all prereqs to run ENA instance which m5 is.
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html